# IntelliJ IDEA incorrect encoding in console output

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

It seems to be really crazy, but I can't do anything with broken encoding in the console of my IntelliJ IDEA.

Things I made to overcome this:

1. Set `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in both `idea.exe.vmoptions` and `idea64.exe.vmoptions` (I use 64 bit version though).
2. Added `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to run/debug configuration of my application.
3. Changed Settings > Editor > File encodings IDE Encoding/Project Encoding/Default encoding for property files to UTF-8.

Having all these done, there is still no luck and symbols are not shown correctly in the console. I tried to debug the `java.io.PrintStream#println(java.lang.String)` method and found out that `System.out.textOut.out.se.cs` equals to windows-1251. No idea where this value is coming from.

This issue has been bothering me for a long time and I was unable to find anything in the web that could help me.

Comment: Please provide some code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `System.out.println("\u0394");` prints [Greek Character Delta](http://unicode-table.com/en/0394/), Δ . What does that print for you?

Comment: @JakeHendy Sorry for delayed answer. The result of `System.out.println("\u0394");` is `?`.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I'll try to provide a sample project, but not sure I'll be able to cause I have another project for testing purposes next to this one and encoding in it's console seems to be ok (unfortunately creating project from scratch is too complex and is not an option for me).

Comment: @mr.nothing in File > Settings > Editor > Console, what's the typeface compared to the "working" project?

Comment: @JakeHendy, It seems that File > Settings > Editor > Console is absent in my version of Intellij Idea (14.1.4). What version do you refer to?

Comment: @mr.nothing apologies. Wrong place. Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Console Font. Is the result of `System.out...` the same in your other testing project?

Comment: @JakeHendy, thanks for responce, checked this, it seems to be identical. The primary one is Monospaced, the secondary one is not configured in both projects.

Comment: @mr.nothing is there a reason that you don't update to the latest version (15.0.2)? Or at least to version 14.1.6

Comment: This is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695918/intellij-idea-console-issue (this one has better title.. so duplicating may not be much use ...

Comment: @Jayan, actully, no, it's not. See accepted answer.

Comment: Official docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-output-encoding.html. @CrazyCoder, it needs fixing of settings file paths for all OSes.

Comment: See also [Unicode characters appear as question marks in IntelliJ IDEA console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082343/unicode-characters-appear-as-question-marks-in-intellij-idea-console)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This works for me.

1. Close your intellij idea
2. Search and open file idea.exe.vmoptions inside idea installed, for example: "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.2\bin".
   After add next line: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
3. (Optional) if you have file idea64.exe.vmoptions, add the same line too.
4. Start your intellij idea.

Comment: Thanks!! This is also accessible from `Help >  Edit custom VM options...` then restart IntelliJ. I literally tried everything: changing encoding settings everywhere in IntelliJ, changing JVM options set by properties file, build.gradle file, IntelliJ, run configuration, environment variable, etc. Also tried changing system wide encoding nothing worked but this.

Comment: Two points:

- I highly recommend the option of @Nicolas because the path from me was not under program files but `C:\Users\name\.IdeaIXXX\config\idea64.exe.vmoptions`
- If it still does not work, verify that the encoding of your file is also in `UTF8`, @chenyi1976 put a good tutorial just below

Answer (score 20):

try

```
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
```

instead of

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 14):

You may have modified the wrong file，

not : `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA xxxx\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions`

should be: `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.IntelliJIdeaxxxx\config\idea64.exe.vmoptions`

you can add both `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and `-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: For version `2020.x`, I found a config file along this path: `C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.x\idea64.exe.vmoptions`. Added these two parameters, restarted and now the text is displayed is right. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

My theory is that your java class file are using "windows-1251" encoding, and you need to set it "UTF-8".

looks at the screenshots below.
[image]
[image]

To reset all files encoding, you can manually edit encodings.xml.
[image]
You can change the default file encoding in settings dialog.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input, but my problem was a little bit different.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA uses the operating system's shell internally as the console. In Windows that's Command Prompt. So if adding...

```
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

... to your VM Options under `Help -> Edit Custom VM Options` doesn't help, ensure your shell supports UTF-8 characters in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

In Intelij coding `java` console

```
System.out.println("Hà nội");  // unicode content
```

Using SDK amazon corretto version ... can help you println unicode console

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me is set environment variable JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS
Run in win cmd

```
setx JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

And restart IDE.

Answer (score 2):

The garbled characters have been resolved with the following settings.
(IntelliJ IDEA Community 2022.2)

```
 - Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Runner > Environment vairables.
 - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17xyd.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you use gradle you can just add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

to your `%userprofile%\\.gradle\gradle.properties` file (or `gradle.properties` on project level).

Ref.: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/common_caching_problems.html#system_file_encoding

Answer (score 1):

This helps me:

By default, IntelliJ IDEA uses the system encoding to view console output.

1. In the **Settings** dialog (Ctrl + Alt + S), select **Editor** | **General** | **Console**.
2. Select the default encoding from the **Default Encoding** list.
3. Click **OK** to apply the changes.
4. Reopen your console.

From [jetbrains.com](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html#file-encoding-settings)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, examining `System.out.textOut.out.se.cs` in debug hinted that IDEA [picked up maven surefire arguments](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206423669-Junit-Maven-surefire-plugin-settings) for every JUnit Run Configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <!-- force 7-bit default encoding to ensure that nothing depends on it -->
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=ASCII</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I've resolved this by adding `-Didea.maven.surefire.disable.argLine=true` to the [idea64.exe.vmoptions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties) file.

See also: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-output-encoding.html.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has come across this problem and nothing works on the top answer, try to download another JDK version and use at SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As @ogkasa mentioned, if you have such a problem and nothing helps, just try to install another JDK version. Me personally tried every possible solution but none worked. So i just rolled back to JDK 17 and now cyrillic (which was my problem) works properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Polish letters (Polskie litery)** I got with *@Vadzim's* tips:

**1. Edit POM.xml**

```xml
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**2. Edit idea64.exe.vmoptions file** by adding
`-Didea.maven.surefire.disable.argLine=true`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).