# Intellij IDEA incorrect encoding in console output and jsp in web

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, utf-8, console

It seems so difficult to understand, my web application is incorrect encoding in some places where use the bootstrap's plugin: dataTables, but others are correct.
Like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ylmj.png)

I have already done something set tomcat's VM option `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, which can solve this problem. However, the console output is incorrect.

In actually, I have referenced the solutions in StackOverflow.
For example, from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231291/intellij-idea-incorrect-encoding-in-console-output)

1. Set `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in both `idea.exe.vmoptions` and `idea64.exe.vmoptions`.
2. Changed **Settings > Editor > File encodings IDE Encoding/Project Encoding/Default encoding** for property files to `UTF-8`.
3. Set tomcat's VM option `-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8` instead of `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. Year, console output is correct, but JSP is not.

Making the console output and JSP display correct encoding at the same time is so difficult. It has confused me a long time.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The jvm options you set fir IDE itself (in exe.vmoptions file) has no relation to how your application handles the encoding. Check e.g. https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8

Comment: Dear Andrey, because I don't have 50 rep, so only reply to you by this way, sorry.That's a good idea, thanks! I notice that my jsp import js which contain some Chinese character, in such situation, the jsp is incorrect encoding. With the help of your website, I understand that the incorrect encoding is caused by tomcat.But so far I can't solve this problem.