# is there a way to print Characters from different languages on java?

Tags: java

I've been working on an assignment in java but when i try to write any Amharic characters they turn into boxes

for example, when I try to print this Amharic character (አማርኛ) on IntelliJ or net beans it shows it as little boxes

if anyone is familiar with this please take a look, thanks in advance.

Comment: The "little boxes" mean your **font** doesn't have glyphs for those characters; change your font.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231291/intellij-idea-incorrect-encoding-in-console-output

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to the output console in IntelliJ. Default the console encoding is UTF-8. You can edit this setting.

Go to help >> edit custom vm options and add (first click "create" if it's your first time there):
"-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8" (but replace UTF-8 with the one you need)

Google for "console encoding" + name of your editor if you want more information. Good luck! :)

Comment: Incorrect character encoding will usually get you `?` question marks, not boxes. Boxes is what fonts use to display characters that are not in the font, so OP is likely having font issues, not character set issues.

Comment: i actually was working on a java fx project and i cant print these characters on the console nor can i set them on buttons or labels, how do you think i can fix this?

Comment: @m.prime As Andreas has commented, your issue is at least partly the font. If you're using JavaFX then use a [`javafx.scene.text.Font`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Font.html) capable of displaying the needed characters.

Answer (score 0):

You a need a font that supoorts Amharic.

- If you don't have already one installed download for example
  [Abyssinica SIL](https://software.sil.org/abyssinica/download/) Or 
  [WashRa
  free-geez-font](https://ethiopiansoftware.com/Tag/free-geez-font/) or [ethiopia-jiret](https://fonts2u.com/ethiopia-jiret.font)

I am using Abyssinica SIL as an example below and NetBeans IDE

**Editor**

- unpack the zip file a and install the font by running "AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf" file
- In Netbeans IDE select **Tools** > **Options**  and click the **Fonts & Colors** icon
- On the Syntax tab click the braces `(...)` on the right of the Font field and choose the Abyssinica SIL font you just installed, and click OK.
- Amharic text should now be correctly desplyed in the editor window but not in the output window. For the output follow below steps

**Output**

- In NetBeans Ouput window right click and select **Settings...** , click the **Miscellaneous** icon, and then click the **Output** tab
- Click the **Import...** button
- Click the **Browse...** button and choose the **Zip** file you downloaded above.(AbyssinicaSIL-2.000.zip)
- click **OK** to close the **Select Options to import window** you'll get a warning "Import may irreversibly overwrite your current settings..." You can trust me on this and ignore the warning and click **Yes** to continue and restart NetBeans.
- After the restart: right click on the Ouput window and select **Settings...** > **Miscellaneous** > **Output** Click on the `(...)` button to the right of the **Font** field and choose the Abyssinica SIL font and click **OK**. Amharic text will now render correctly in the Output window.

ይህ መልስ ጠቃሚ ነበር ብዬ ተስፋ አደርጋለሁ ፡፡ መልካም ምሽት እመኛለሁ ፡፡

Comment: sorry but the font isn't showing up on netbeans settings the font is installed and it shows up on apps like Microsoft word but not on netbeans, what should i do?