# Reading a file using utf-8 that is encoded in utf-8 doesn't work, but reading the same file using "windows-1252" or "iso-8859-1" does

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

What is happening here? Why when I read the file using utf-8 does it output questionmarks in the console?

This is a minimal working example:

[image]

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    
import static org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString;
import static org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile;
    
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    
        System.out.println("---------");
        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println("æ ø å");
        System.out.println("æ ø å");
        System.out.println("æ ø å");
    
        File inputFile  = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/input.md");
        File outputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/output.md");
    
        String content, encoding;
    
        System.out.println("--------- windows-1252");
        encoding = "windows-1252";
        content = readFileToString(inputFile, encoding);
        System.out.println(content);
    
    
        System.out.println("--------- iso-8859-1");
        encoding = "iso-8859-1";
        content = readFileToString(inputFile, encoding);
        System.out.println(content);
    
    
        System.out.println("--------- utf-8");
        encoding = "utf-8";
        content = readFileToString(inputFile, encoding);
        System.out.println(content);
    
    
        writeStringToFile(outputFile, content, encoding);
    
    }
    
}
```

Where `input.md` contains: (encoded in UTF-8)

```
This is input.md. 'æ' 'ø' 'å'
```

Running the above code yields

```
---------
windows-1252
æ ø å
æ ø å
æ ø å
--------- windows-1252
This is file C. 'æ' 'ø' 'å'.
--------- iso-8859-1
This is file C. 'æ' 'ø' 'å'.
--------- utf-8
This is file C. '�' '�' '�'.
```

**Why do I get `�` when I read the file using UTF-8? This is especially weird since the file is encoded in UTF-8**.

**UPDATE**: My console is set to "UTF-8":

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the hex values of each char in string extracted from the input file:

[image]

Here is a better screenshot of the hex isolated:

[image]

Comment: An image of code is useless.  We can’t copy and paste it, we can’t run it or test it, we can’t search it, sight impaired users can’t do anything with it, and speaking for myself, I can barely see it when it’s scaled to fit in the page.  Please edit your question and augment that image with text—preferably one code-formatted text block containing your code, and another containing your output.

Comment: @VGR I edited the question, I hope it's clearer now :)

Comment: Does it help to add `systemProp.file.encoding=utf-8` into `gradle.properties` file in the project root directory? Does it help to switch to **IntelliJ IDEA** in the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Build and run using**?

Comment: Also try to set UTF-8 for the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | File Encodings | **Project Encoding**.

Comment: @Andrey Everything was already sat to UTF-8 in the File-Encodings tab under settings. [screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/fe716d80658af416987e46f5d1aedb56.png). And no it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine to me, and your `output.md` file looks OK. So this is most likely just an issue with the console output.

The Unicode characters you are experimenting with are encoded as the same single bytes in both Windows-1252 and ISO-8859-1 (`æ = 0xE6`, `ø = 0xF8`, `å = 0xE5`), but are encoded as multiple bytes in UTF-8 (`æ = 0xC3 0xA6`, `ø = 0xC3 0xB8`, `å = 0xC3 0xA5`).

Reading a UTF-8 encoded file as either Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1 will decode each byte individually, producing a `string` containing a separate `char` for each byte, and those `char`s will have the same numeric values as the bytes.  So, you *should* be ending up with a `string` containing chars `0x00C3 0x00A6`, `0x00C3 0x00B8`, and `0x00C3 0x00A5`.  Outputting those `char`s to the console as Windows-1252 *should* be showing as `Ã¦ Ã¸ Ã¥`, not as `æ ø å`.

On the other hand, reading a UTF-8 encoded file as UTF-8 will decode the file properly, producing a `string` with `char`s `0x00E6`, `0x00F8`, and `0x00E5`.  Writing that `string` to a UTF-8 encoded file should be producing the correct byte sequences (`0xC3 0xA6`, `0xC3 0xB8`, and `0xC3 0xA5`), but outputting that same `string` as Windows-1252 risks data loss, but you *should* be seeing `æ ø å` as expected, since Windows-1252 does support those Unicode characters.

So, your results are actually backwards from what I would expect.  Even though `Charset.defaultCharset()` is reporting Windows-1252, I suspect your console is actually using a different charset for its output.

I suggest you print out the numeric values of the individual `char`s of the `content` string to see exactly how `input.md` is actually being decoded by each encoding.  You *should* be getting the `char` values I mentioned above.

Comment: EDIT: I fixed the issue, you were right it was issues related to the console output.

Answer (score 1):

For people with similar issues, the problem lies with the encoding of the console (as @Remy Lebeau points out too).

I fixed the issue by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56430344/14309129)

Actually, I followed @Nicolas answer in the comment to eh mentioned answer:

> This is also accessible from Help >  Edit custom VM options... then restart IntelliJ. I literally tried everything: changing encoding settings everywhere in IntelliJ, changing JVM options set by properties file, build.gradle file, IntelliJ, run configuration, environment variable, etc. Also tried changing system wide encoding nothing worked but this

Now I get the expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar issue and what I found was that *some* JDKs on my system yield a `file.encoding` of `Cp1252` instead of UTF-8. I don't know why.

You can then either add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` or if you use Gradle you can just add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to your `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` (`%userprofile%\.gradle\gradle.properties`) or on a project level into your `gradle.properties`.

Or try to reinstall the JDK with the desired `file.encoding`.