# How to retrieve/print proper Hindi meaning text in Console from a english-hindi.sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have downloaded a word meaning Android **sqlite.db** dictionary file. By fetching SQL query I got

```
enslishWord="plausible";
hindiMeaning="lR;kHkklh]diViw.kZ]";
```

By using Hindi **Typeface** in **TextView** I got proper Hindi meaning. If I try to print by `System.out.println(hindiMeaning);` it prints `lR;kHkklh]diViw.kZ]`

I am confused about the problem and looking for a solution. Please, check the raw Android **sqlite.db** Github link in comment sections.

Comment: https://github.com/shahidul2k9/english-to-hindi-dictionary/blob/f818bef83663b3d3e815440a9414658f9bb845c6/app/src/main/assets/english-hindi.sqlite

Comment: how are storing hindi ? . is it in UTF8 and unicode

Comment: english-hindi.sqlite is ANSI encoding. If I convert it into UTF-8  the englsih-hindi.sqlite doesn't work. The SqliteLog errors                                                                                                         E/SQLiteLog: (11) database corruption at line 65059 of [b2325a6e1c]                   E/SQLiteLog: (11) database corruption at line 65209 of [b2325a6e1c]                 E/SQLiteLog: (11) statement aborts at 3: [] database disk image is malformed ) 2021-07-29 12:22:56.283 E/SQLiteDatabase: Database corruption detected in open()

Answer (score 0):

add this class

```
public class typeface extends TypefaceSpan {
    Typeface typeface;

    public typeface(String family, Typeface typeface) {
        super(family);
        this.typeface = typeface;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setTypeface(typeface);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setTypeface(typeface);
    }

}`
```

Add this method to you activity

```
 public SpannableString spannableString(String string, String your_working_hindi_font_name , Context context) {

    SpannableString span = new SpannableString(string);
    span.setSpan(new typeface("", Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "" + your_working_hindi_font_name + ".ttf")), 0, span.length(), span.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    return span;

}
public void spannableToast(SpannableString text, Context context) {
    Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

call method
to show toast

```
spannableToast(spannableString(normal, "hindi" , getContext()) , getContext());
```

to set text

```
 phoneTv.setText( spannableString(normal, "hindi" , getContext()));
```

Comment: In System.out.println(text);  and clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("Facebook Post", text);

        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clipData); it gives lR;kHkklh]diViw.kZ] .. but it works in toast message.

Comment: To copy or get it to in your clip data set the text to a text view 1st then get a text from the textview.

Answer (score 0):

> If I try to print by System.out.println(hindiMeaning); it prints lR;kHkklh]diViw.kZ].

**Are you trying to print the non-English characters in Console?**

**android.graphics.Typeface** is an Android-specific class whereas **System.out.println** is a Java-specific function. You can't expect the Java console to print out the non-English characters by default.

In Android Studio the default encoding can be set in the **studio64.exe.vmoptions** file as an ordinary VM parameter. This file is located inside the root folder of your Android Studio installation and contains a set of JVM parameters. Add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` there to set encoding in UTF-8.

Alternatively, you can change the option via the settings.

Reference: [IntelliJ IDEA incorrect encoding in console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231291/intellij-idea-incorrect-encoding-in-console-output)

[image: Android Studio Settings]

Comment: english-hindi.sqlite is ANSI encoding. If I convert it into UTF-8  the englsih-hindi.sqlite doesn't work.  The SqliteLog errors  E/SQLiteLog: (11) database corruption at line 65059 of [b2325a6e1c]  E/SQLiteLog: (11) database corruption at line 65209 of [b2325a6e1c] E/SQLiteLog: (11) statement aborts at 3: [] database disk image is malformed )  E/SQLiteDatabase: Database corruption detected in open()