# intellij idea console output not supporting turkish charecter

Tags: java, intellij-idea, character-encoding

[IntelliJ IDEA incorrect encoding in console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231291/intellij-idea-incorrect-encoding-in-console-output)

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html

Turkish characters are not supported in intellij idea's terminal after run command.
I tried the above two links but I couldn't solve the problem.
[console output photo-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDOGW.jpg)

Comment: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));` What does that give? What is your OS?

Comment: Terminal output: UTF-8, My OS is Windows 10

Comment: Try setting the IDE encoding to `Windows-1254`. What btw does `chcp` give in cmd.exe?

Comment: I tried the Windows-1254, the problem persisted. chcp cmd output:857(Turkish).  I tested everything from scratch in the virtual windows operating system, there is no problem there. I think the problem is in my operating system

Comment: Hmm. Is it the case that *some* Turkish characters are OK? Have a go with IBM857

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a related issue on YouTrack:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291006/Running-the-Java-project-by-using-the-JDK-18-prints-the-garbled-

Feel free to watch it in order to be notified once it has updates. See [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) if you are not familiar with YouTrack.

Answer (score 0):

For turkish character support, you chould choose the international global UTF-8 format.

In IntelliJIdea 
**File / Settings / Editor / File Encoding** / *.properties
Choose -> **Default encoding for properties files UTF-8

By the use of BOM configurations you can find the correct solution for your files. Do not forget that some choices of BOM for some class files can cause various \uxxxx errors like '\ufeff' error

Moreover you could choose also Global Encoding and Project encoding values just given above in the same tab as UTF-8 to get a more general solution for the future projects.

[Screenshot of the web content created by the use of many components bfrom messages.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLYnk.png)

[printed text or response from local server with turkish characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAT5w.png)

[Settings Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQAdA.png)