# I want to display Greek unicode characters but i get "?" instead on ouput

Tags: java, string, unicode, character

I want to print n Greek characters in Java starting from alpha (whitch has the "\u03B1" code).This is what I had in mind:

```
String T = "";
  for(int i = 0,aux = 0;i<n;i++)
       {
           aux = '\u03B1' + i;
           T +=Character.toString((char)aux);
       }
  System.out.println(T);
```

But it prints n question marks instead.

Let's say n=3,on the output i get "???".

I thought that maybe my method is wrong but then again if I try something like this:

```
System.out.println("\u03B1\u03B2\u03B3");
```

I get the same output:"???"

Why do I get this output instead of the desired characters and how can I print them like I want to?

Note:I use IntelliJ as IDE and my OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

I think it has something to do with default Charset set in the system. We can use the following line to print the default charset at runtime:

`System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());`

May be your system doesn't have UTF-8 set by default, in this case, we can convert the string to UTF-8 before printing, e.g.:

`System.out.println(new String(T.getBytes(),"UTF-8"));`

This prints alpha, beta and gamma to console.

P.S. don't know if it's a typo but `T +=Character.toString((char)aux2);` needs to be changed to `T +=Character.toString((char)aux);`

Answer (score 0):

You get the invalid character output because the console output of your IDE is (probably) set to Windows default charset encoding, [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), but Java natively uses [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) encoding.

To fix the problem, you should set the charset encoding of your IDE's console output to UTF-8, e.g. by using the instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082343/unicode-characters-appear-as-question-marks-in-intellij-idea-console).