# Why the code in the Body build fail when I just remove a single word?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("新聞");
    }
}
```

Above code is very simple,and it works fine.But if I remove a single word '聞', Intellij Idea warn me:

```
����: ����GBK�Ĳ���ӳ���ַ�
        System.out.println("�?");
```

My Intellij edition information shows below:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-201.7223.91, built on April 30, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.6+8-b765.40 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1990M
Cores: 6
Non-Bundled Plugins: training
```

And I use Gradle 5.2.1 to build the project.

Comment: What encoding are you using in IntelliJ?

Comment: My encoding using in IntelliJ is UTF-8，and my os encoding is gbk.

Comment: @Hongyuan Most probably something is wrong with encoding. To make sure that you have configured it correctly check the answers:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082370/12844632
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58886877/12844632

If everything is fine with that please create a new issue in [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) and attach a compressed [logs folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) after restarting the IDE and reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Egor Klepikov. Answer stackoverflow.com/a/58886877/12844632 works fine for me.