# What could be the reason about the encoding problem (Coding with Java/using Turkish Characters in a String) in IntelliJ Idea Run Console?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, utf-8, ide

Here's my code and console output:

Code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int sayi = 19;

if(sayi < 20)
{
    System.out.println("Sayı 20'den küçük!");
}
}
```

}

Output:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=13784:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\JavaDemos\conditionals\out\production\conditionals Main
Say? 20'den k���k!

Process finished with exit code 0

Also UTF-8 is chosen in the bottom-right side.

[image: Output]

I've encountered a problem as the title suggests; which is an encoding problem in IntelliJ Idea Run Console (the version I'm currently using: IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Ultimate Edition)).

[image: version]

I've tried these to solve the problem but nothing worked:

1. Added these in both idea64.exe.vmoptions and idea.properties:
   -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

[image: idea64.exe.vmoptions]

[image: idea.properties]

2. Settings --> Editor --> File Encodings

Global Encoding : UTF - 8
Project Encoding : UTF - 8

In Properties Files (*.properties)
Default encoding for properties files : UTF - 8

[image: File Encodings]

3. Settings --> Editor --> General --> Console
   Default Encoding : UTF - 8

[image: Console]

Thanks in advance for all of your replies.

Comment: Seems to be the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71685543/2711488)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've solved the issue via this link it's the same topic but when i create this post, couldn't see it :)