# IDEA console print garbled text instead of Chinese when I use java18

Tags: java, intellij-idea, character-encoding, java-18

I'm a Chinese programmer. Today I try to upgrade my project JDK version from 16 to 18.(also upgrade IDEA2021 to 2022) But I came across a problem, IDEA console print garbled text instead of Chinese. Here is the code and console output.
[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSIze.jpg)

I tried many ways to solve it but I failed, then I reran it in CMD and github CI, then this bug disappeared.
[CMD image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/886Uq.jpg)

When I rollbacked my JDK to 16, this bug also disappeared, it seems that this bug only happens in JDK18 and IDEA console, how can I solve it?

---

Addition:
My unit test also broken.
[bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUKgc.jpg)

---

Addition2:
I tried different chcp, it outputed correctly.
[65001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFpQf.jpg)
[936](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGZ7P.jpg)

---

I thought is a problem about JEP400,so I ran these code

```
System.out.println("Default charset : " + Charset.defaultCharset());
System.out.println("file.encoding   : " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
System.out.println("native.encoding : " + System.getProperty("native.encoding"));
System.out.println("你好");
```

on JDK16, it printed:

```
Default charset : UTF-8
file.encoding   : UTF-8
native.encoding : null
你好
```

on JDK17, it printed

```
Default charset : UTF-8
file.encoding   : UTF-8
native.encoding : GBK
你好
```

on JDK18, it printed

```
Default charset : UTF-8
file.encoding   : UTF-8
native.encoding : GBK
���
```

Comment: Out of interest, in that cmd.exe window, what do you get from command `chcp`? Useful also to know output of `System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));`

Comment: I got  `活动代码页: 936` when I command `chcp`.  file.encoding is UTF-8

Comment: I found a issue about this problem https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291006

Comment: DId you try that gbk thing?

Comment: Isn’t this exactly the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71685543/2711488)?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291006
I added `-Dfile.encoding=gbk` in VM option and solved it.
I think it's a bug of IDEA.

Comment: You mean you did that and it solved it?

Comment: yes,  the only way to fix the issue is to use `-Dfile.encoding=GBK` which is far from perfect.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if `-Dfile.encoding=x-mswin-936` would work just as well. I also wonder if the encoding of your files is *actually* UTF-8 or something else, but I'd need to see one of your actual files to find out

Comment: I tried mswin-936, it worked. My code is on `https://github.com/RShock/fumaSim/blob/main/src/test/java/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87Test.java` . IDEA and VSCode shows that my file is UTF-8

Comment: Yes the file seems to be UTF-8. The other encoding corresponds to your Windows cmd.exe