# Why do Java programs created using Gradle generate garbled code when running

Tags: java, gradle

#### question

I created a Java program using Gradle But the running result is garbled code.

The Gradle task display is also garbled as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

#### environment

Gradle

```bash
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-11-29 14:08:57 UTC
Revision:     28aca86a7180baa17117e0e5ba01d8ea9feca598

Kotlin:       1.9.20
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          21.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 21.0.2+13-LTS-58)
OS:           Windows 11 10.0 amd64
```

Java

```bash
java version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58, mixed mode, sharing)
```

build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This is a general purpose Gradle build.
 * To learn more about Gradle by exploring our Samples at https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/samples
 */

plugins {
    id("java")
}

tasks.register("runCode", JavaExec::class) {
    defaultCharacterEncoding = "UTF-8"

    println("测试Code" + defaultCharacterEncoding)

    mainClass = "com.stu.Main"
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath

    group = "Exec"
    description = "运行指定代码"
}

tasks.register("runStu") {
    for (sourceSetContainer in sourceSets) {
        println(sourceSetContainer)
    }

    println(sourceSets)
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile>().configureEach {

}

tasks.withType(JavaExec::class.java) {
    val args:List<String> = ArrayList()
//    args.addLast("-Dsun.stdout.encoding=GBK")
//    args.addLast("-Dsun.stderr.encoding=GBK")
//    args.addLast("-Dfile.encoding=COMPAT")
//    args.addLast("-Dnative.encoding=UTF-8")
    this.jvmArgs = args
//  val args = this.jvmArgs

//    args?.addLast("-Dsun.stdout.encoding=utf8")
//    args?.addLast("-Dsun.stderr.encoding=utf8")
//    this.jvmArgs = args;
    println(this.jvmArgs)
}
```

com.stu.Main

```java
package com.stu;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.test00();
    }

    public void test00() {
        System.out.println("中文测试");
        System.out.println("sun.stdout.encoding = " + System.getProperty("sun.stdout.encoding"));
        System.out.println("sun.stderr.encoding = " + System.getProperty("sun.stderr.encoding"));
        System.out.println("      file.encoding = " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
        System.out.println("    native.encoding = " + System.getProperty("native.encoding"));
    }
}
```

#### run result

Gradle Run

```bash
> Task :runCode
涓枃娴嬭瘯
sun.stdout.encoding = null
sun.stderr.encoding = null
      file.encoding = UTF-8
    native.encoding = GBK

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 746ms
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Java Run

```bash
java "-Dfile.encoding=GBK" "-Dsun.stdout.encoding=GBK" "-Dsun.stderr.encoding=GBK" com.stu.Main
中文测试
sun.stdout.encoding = GBK
sun.stderr.encoding = GBK
      file.encoding = GBK
    native.encoding = GBK


java "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" "-Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8" "-Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8" com.stu.Main
涓枃娴嬭瘯
sun.stdout.encoding = UTF-8
sun.stderr.encoding = UTF-8
      file.encoding = UTF-8
    native.encoding = GBK
```

I have tried the answer to this question

[idea-console-print-garbled-text-instead-of-chinese-when-i-use-java18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989161/idea-console-print-garbled-text-instead-of-chinese-when-i-use-java18)

I want to know what caused the garbled code?

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a terminal that can't handle Unicode. I doubt this is a Java or Gradle problem. What terminal are you running this in?

Comment: I am using Windows Powershell

Answer (score 0):

This is JDK18 issue,change to other version JDK is Okay. ref to https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/20267

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35752359)